# Inserting Multiple Input Values into one database column

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert multiple input values into one table column.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php   $shot = $_POST['leadShot'];

foreach ($shot as $shotall) {
    $leadShot[] = implode(' - ', $shotall);
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO leaderboards (leadName,leadDate,leadScore,leadShot) VALUES ('$name','$date','$score','$shot')")or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

And then I have the following from code:

```
<li class="field"><h2>Hole 1</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 2</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 3</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 4</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 5</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 6</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 7</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 8</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
    <li class="field"><h2>Hole 9</h2><input class="input" name="leadShot[]" id="leadShot[]" type="text" value="" size="103" /></li>
```

I want to be able to have Hole 1-9 inserting into one column?

Comment: What is the SQL type of leadShot?

Comment: Not an answer, but I assume you're familiar with [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)?

Comment: Hi, the SQL type of leadShot is text?

Answer (score 1):

> remove the foreach loop.
>   implode Returns a string containing a string representation of all the
>   array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each
>   element.

```
<?php   $shot = $_POST['leadShot'];
          $leadShot = implode(' - ', $shot);
          $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

             mysql_query("INSERT INTO leaderboards 
    (leadName,leadDate,leadScore,leadShot)
     VALUES ('$name','$date','$score','$leadShot')") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize(), which will store that variable as an array:

```
$shot = serialize($leadShot);
```

When retrieving it, simply unserialize it.

Sidenote, use mysqli instead of mysql functions.